# How to obtain the spectral reflectance of a whole object?

Tags: spectrometry

I am interested in the colours of an object in a natural light environment. Specifically, I am interested in obtaining spectral reflectance data (i.e. the particular light wavelength(s) reflected of an object) from an object as viewed by a biological eye. I know it is possible to obtain spectral reflectance data with a spectrophotometer. However, I am more interested in obtaining spectral reflectance data of the whole object. Theoretically, one could do this with a spectrophotometer if the spectral reflectance of the object is measured painstakingly point-by-point. Understandably, this would be a hassle, not to mention the practical problems that will need to be overcome.

Are there apparatuses or a combination of apparatuses and methods that could do this more easily?

P.s. I am not a student of engineering, so forgive my potential ignorance.